# Mapping over props (an array of names) returns the name with a string of commas ("Pam,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,") -- one for each item in the array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm mapping over an array of 20 strings in a React component. The array has been passed to this component as props from a parent. When I pass the result of the function to a JSX element (an h1), it returns just the name. When I pass the same function to a form's placeholder, it returns the name followed by 20 commas. If I change the ID so that the map function returns a different string from the middle of the array, it returns the name with 10 commas on either side. The last item in the array is returned with 20 commas before the name.

I've tried having the function return null or an empty string or just not having an 'else.'

Here is the function:

```
 getTeacherName = () => {
    return this.props.teachers.map(teacher => {
      if (teacher.id == this.props.match.params.id) {
        return teacher.name;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  };
```

Here is where I'm using it and getting the desired response:

```
return (
    <h1>{this.getTeacherName()}'s Schedule</h1>
)
```

Here is where I'm using it and getting the problem:

```
<input
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  placeholder={this.getTeacherName()}
  disabled
/>
```

[Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KPdY.jpg)

Thanks!

Comment: If you're searching for a single teacher's name then you shouldn't use an array. You're subject to default array rendering which may be different under different scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getTeacherName()` method should select the correct teacher and then return the name as follows.

```
getTeacherName = () => {
    let teacherObj = this.props.teachers.find(teacher => (teacher.id == this.props.match.params.id));
     return teacherObj ? teacherObj.name : null;

  };
```

Answer (score 1):

> The **[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in the calling array.

So in your case you should use **[find( predicate )](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)** to find the teacher and then get his name if found.

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter as below

```
 getTeacherName = () => {
    let teacher =  this.props.teachers.filter(teacher => teacher.id == this.props.match.params.id )[0];
   return teacher ? teacher.name : null
  };
```